# Start mariaDB service on Archlinux faild

Tags: mysql, mariadb, archlinux

This is my first time using mysql, and I know that mariadb is the official implementation of mysql on archlinux. At first, I didn't start it according to the method on archwiki, but directly executed mysqld. After that, an error was reported, so I went to archwiki to find a solution.
I follow the steps and executed this

```
# mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql
```

After this, the error is reported as follows

```
× mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.5.10 database server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2021-06-19 11:15:50 CST; 1min 4s ago
       Docs: man:mariadbd(8)
             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
    Process: 1961 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 1962 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 1970 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mariadbd $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 1970 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "MariaDB server is down"
        CPU: 70ms

6月 19 11:15:50 wilson mariadbd[1970]: 2021-06-19 11:15:50 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
6月 19 11:15:50 wilson mariadbd[1970]: 2021-06-19 11:15:50 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
6月 19 11:15:50 wilson mariadbd[1970]: 2021-06-19 11:15:50 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
6月 19 11:15:50 wilson mariadbd[1970]: 2021-06-19 11:15:50 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
6月 19 11:15:50 wilson mariadbd[1970]: 2021-06-19 11:15:50 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table: "Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist". Some plugins may be not loaded
6月 19 11:15:50 wilson mariadbd[1970]: 2021-06-19 11:15:50 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
6月 19 11:15:50 wilson mariadbd[1970]: 2021-06-19 11:15:50 0 [ERROR] Aborting
6月 19 11:15:50 wilson systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
6月 19 11:15:50 wilson systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
6月 19 11:15:50 wilson systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.5.10 database server.
```

Then I add current user to mysql user group. But the problem remains.
How can I do? Can anyone do me a favor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message is a good indicator of what’s wrong:

```
The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
```

If the file is not writable, one of a few things is going on:

1. You’re not starting the service from the `root` account
2. The data directory for the database has the wrong permissions set

For the first item, be sure to prefix the command with `sudo`. MySQL/MariaDB (generally) cannot be started from a normal user account.

For the second, confirm that the data directory (often `/var/lib/MySQL` is owned by the MySQL user and the file permissions are properly restricted (MySQL refuses to run if the data or logging directories are `777` or `755`).

Comment: As you see `cat /etc/group | grep sql` `mysql:x:974:wilson` Now user wilson(current user) is belongs to mysql user group. But the problem remains.